# new session after every request, tomcat backend, apache frontend

Tags: apache, session, tomcat, forwarding

I develop a jsp website using tomcat as backend and apache as frontend redirecting with mod_proxy.

First my configs.

apache:

```
ProxyRequests Off 
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyPass / https://realdomain.tld:8443/proj1/
ProxyPassReverse / https://realdomain.tld:8443/proj1/
<Location />
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
```

When I reload my jsp webpage, every time i get a new session id. When developing on localhost without apache and mod_proxy everything works and I keep the same session id.

For my webapp it is important to keep the same session during the time.

Any Idea how i can tell apache to keep my session. I guess  apache has to redirect the cookie to tomcat right? but how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you change the context path in the proxy (/ -> proj1) you create a whole heap of problems to solve. Your immediate cookie problem can be solved with the [ProxyPassReverseCookiePath](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreversecookiepath) directive. I then suspect you'll find the next problem to solve. You'd be better off redeploying your application as the ROOT web application so that your ProxyPass directive is `ProxyPass / https://realdomain.tld:8443/`

As an aside, it looks like you are proxying to Tomcat's https connector. If you aren't careful you will create security problems for yourself if httpd receives requests over http, proxies them to Tomcat over https and Tomcat treats those requests as being received over a secure channel.

Comment: ProxyPassReverseCookiePath solved it for me. I could not see any other problems evolving. Thanks!